# Test a mobile website for Android or BlackBerry

Tags: android, testing, blackberry

How do I test a mobile website for Android or BlackBerry without having the actual device?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Testing mobile websites

The best way to to test mobile websites is to install an emulator for the phone you want to test on.

### Blackberry

- Detailed installation guide can be found here:
  http://www.cantoni.org/2007/12/18/blackberrysimulator
- Link to device simulator download page:
  https://www.blackberry.com/Downloads/entry.do?code=060AD92489947D410D897474079C1477

### Android

- Detailed installation guide:
  http://androidandme.com/2009/10/news/how-to-install-android-sdk-and-play-with-android-2-0-in-the-emulator/
- Emulator documentation:
  http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html

Answer (score 3):

You can create an account with [DeviceAnywhere](http://www.deviceanywhere.com/) and use the required devices remotely. By this way you can use the browsers of the phones.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out: [Source link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464089/simulators-emulators-for-mobile-browser-testing/464527#464527)

Also might have a look [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/download-google-android-emulator/) there is a link at the bottom of the article.

Comment: Explaining a little about what is in those links would make this answer more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can also test Blackberry Playbook web-site using ripple simulator you can download at following link.
https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/download/ripple

Answer (score 0):

For android, you can download http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

Comment: So far my understanding you should be able to browse from the emulator.